Live AAC and H264 data into live stream
I have a remote camera that captures H264 encoded video data and AAC encoded audio data, places the data into a custom ring buffer, which then is sent to a Node.js socket server, where the packet of information is detected as audio or video and then handled accordingly. That data should turn into a live stream, the protocol doesn't matter, but the delay has to be around ~4 seconds and can be played on iOS and Android devices.
After reading hundreds of pages of documentation, questions, or solutions on the internet, I can't seem to find anything about handling two separate streams of AAC and H264 data to create a live stream.
Despite attempting many different ways of achieving this goal, even having a working implementation of HLS, I want to revisit ALL options of live streaming, and I am hoping someone out there can give me advice or guidance to specific documentation on how to achieve this goal.
To be specific, this is our goal:

Stream AAC and H264 data from remote cellular camera to a server which will do some work on that data to live stream to one user (possibly more users in the future) on a mobile iOS or Android device
Delay of the live stream should be a maximum of ~4 seconds, if the user has bad signal, then a longer delay is okay, as we obviously cannot do anything about that.
We should not have to re-encode our data. We've explored WebRTC, but that requires OPUS audio packets and thus requires us to re-encode the data, which would be expensive for our server to run.

Any and all help, ranging from re-visiting an old approach we took to exploring new ones, is appreciated.
I can provide code snippets as well for our current implementation of LLHLS if it helps, but I figured this post is already long enough.
I've tried FFmpeg with named pipes, I expected it to just work, but FFmpeg kept blocking on the first named pipe input. I thought of just writing the data out to two files and then using FFmpeg, but it's continuous data and I don't have enough knowledge on FFmpeg on how I could use that type of implementation to create one live stream.
I've tried implementing our own RTSP server on the camera using Gstreamer (our camera had its RTSP server stripped out, wasn't my call) but the camera's flash storage cannot handle having GStreamer on it, so that wasn't an option.
My latest attempt was using a derivation of hls-parser to create an HLS manifest and mux.js to create MP4 containers for .m4s fragmented mp4 files and do an HLS live stream. This was my most successful attempt, where we successfully had a live stream going, but the delay was up to 16 seconds, as one would expect with HLS live streaming. We could drop the target duration down to 2 seconds and get about 6-8 seconds delay, but this could be unreliable, as these cameras could have no signal making it relatively expensive to send so many IDR frames with such low bandwidth.
With the delay being the only factor left, I attempted to upgrade the implementation to support Apple's Low Latency HLS. It seems to work, as the right partial segments are getting requested and everything that makes LLHLS is working as intended, but the delay isn't going down when played on iOS' native AVPlayer, as a matter of fact, it looks like it worsened.
I would also like to disclaim, my knowledge on media streaming is fairly limited. I've learned most of what I speak of in this post over the past 3 months by reading RFCs, documentation, and stackoverflow/reddit questions and answers. If anything appears to be confusing, it might be just my lack of understanding of it.

How are you synchronizing the separate AAC and H.264 streams?  And, how exactly are these streams separate in the first place?  I'd start investigation there, as you're probably creating more work for yourself at the very beginning.

@tzuleger (1) "The delay was up to 16 seconds" Is it possible it was waiting for a keyframe before displaying any picture? Do you see an immediate picture if your first muxing is done with an h264 keyframe? Try it like this... Get one packet of SPS, get one packet of PPS and finally get one packet of some test h264 keyframe (IDR). You need the metadata (SPS and PPS) and also a keyframe before the first picture can show. (2) "Making it expensive to send so many IDR frames" You could store the PPS and SPS on server since it's always the same data, store/overwrite the most recent key.

@tzuleger this way whenever you send out to a connection (viewer) your script should first send the stored SPS/PPS/Keyframe as first data, and from there it can also send through any most recent frames (non-key) as received from the camera. Of course each time the data is muxed into being MP4 fragments.

@Brad We collect the video/audio data inside ring buffers and send them out to the server per frame. When the server receives the data, the data is synchronized by looking at the time stamps for each frame. When enough frames are collected to meet the partial duration, then the data is packed side-by-side into the mdat portion of an fmp4 fragmented file. I have no doubt that we may be doing more work than we should, but it was the only solution we could really come up given the knowledge we have.

@VC.One Thank you, we do make sure that the SPS and PPS is collected before the keyframe and then the keyframe always hits our server first before any other frames. The way we pack the data is by checking each frame's time stamps against eachother until the difference of time stamps equals the target partial duration, where then we would pack the frames into an mdat for an fmp4 file. Does that make sense? I apologize if there's anything I'm leaving out that makes this confusing.

@VC.One Also, just to clarify, with partial segments, there may not always be a keyframe in the segment, as the protocol sometimes expects. When there is a keyframe, then the manifest will list it as "INDEPENDENT=YES". Full segments always start with a keyframe.
While reading your question though, I'm curious to know if FMP4 even works with LLHLS, should we change our container format from FMP4 to TS?
